# setTimeout Only Working for One Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have two tables that I want to refresh every so often. Both are using pretty much the same javascript, except that one works and the other doesn't.
Here is the first table's code (Only refreshes once):

```
function refreshTable() {
    $('#tablefill').load('table.php', function(){
       table1refr=setTimeout(refreshTable, 10000);
    $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
       document.getElementById(value).innerHTML = '-';
    });
    });
}
```

And here is the second (Refreshes every 10 seconds, as it should):

```
function refreshFileTable() {
    $('#filetablefill').load('filetable.php', function(){
       table2refr=setTimeout(refreshFileTable, 10000);
    });
}
```

I tried switching setTimeout to setInterval on both of them, which worked, but the browser tab would completely freeze after a minute or so of sitting on the page. If you could suggest a way to prevent that, I would love to use setInterval.

Comment: There's no need to have table1refr=setTimeout(refreshTable, 10000); replace this with just setTimeout(refreshTable, 10000); Also, the variable 'selected' in the .each() loop is never initialized.

Comment: @frenchie You don't know if there is no need, maybe he wants to clear the timeout from outside somewhere.

Comment: @m90 `selected` is an array containing strings that correspond to buttons later on the page.
@frenchie I realize that, I had those there for something else.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder: yea, that's a possibility but I from the code given it looks unnecessary.

Comment: Did you checked the response from your table.php, is it OK.

Comment: @Hemant_Negi Yes, it displays it fine, and I can view it fine on it's own, it just doesn't refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use setInterval  you don't need to set it every time, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(refreshFileTable,1000);
})

function refreshFileTable() {
    $('#filetablefill').load('filetable.php', function(){
       // do nothing or remove this handler entirely
       // if you were setting intervals over here you have created new interval in every 10 seconds         and thats how it hanged 
    });
}
```

Comment: I just realized that I was creating a new setInterval each time it reloaded. This is much better. Thanks a ton!